# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in refCreateUser in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I see the following error in the console. I am not sure how i can provide both email and password in ref.CreateUser

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

This is function

```
function so_passwd() {
  var email = $("#so_email").val();
  var password = $("#so_pass").val();
  ref.createUser({
    email,
    password
  }, function(error) {
    if (error === null) {
      console.log("User created successfully");
    } else {
      console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Well, for one, that's invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
function so_passwd(){
    var email = $("#so_email").val();
    var password = $("#so_pass").val();
    ref.createUser({
        "email": email
        "password": password
    }, function(error) {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log("User created successfully");
    } else {
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    }
});
```